# transformZ not working

Tags: css

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zulifa/edit?html,css,output) of what I have so far.

I don't understand why tranformZ is not working.  Here is my html:

```
<div class="pyramid-container">
  <div id="pyramid">
    <div>child div of #pyramid</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

And below is my css, I have perspective set and transform-style set to preserve-3d so I am not suer what is wrong.

```
.pyramid-container {
  perspective: 800px;
}

#pyramid {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: 116px 200px 116px;
}

#pyramid div {
  position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 200px solid transparent;  /* left arrow slant */
    border-right: 200px solid transparent; /* right arrow slant */
    border-bottom: 200px solid #2f2f2f; /* bottom, add background color here */
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
  opacity: .5;
}

#pyramid div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateZ(80em);
}
```

Comment: #pyramid doesn't have any child

Comment: @vals apologies, I have updated the question but the same problem exists

Comment: there is a jsbin link in the question.  i would have expected the triangle to appear closer or further away depending on the value I set but it never changes no matter what value I use for translateZ

Comment: apologies but you keep telling me to fix html that is fixed

Comment: Yes now the question is updated. Have you researched this issue at all? You could [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ) and this will show you how to correctly apply Translate-Z adjustments using the `perspective` co-property.

Comment: [here is another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/K3yRH/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `font-size` is set to zero, so transforming the element `80em` equals `0px`. Use another unit for the transform or increase your font size.

Comment: I would never have realized the font size would affect this.  I thought I was going mad.  Thank you!